# How to use KSoap 2 in android

Tags: java, android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I've just came across to ksoap2 for using my own asp .net webservices in android apps.
I've found few great resources over internet and I've implemented my webservice in android app.

Following is the webservice's response I consumed:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <CheckAuthenticationResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <CheckAuthenticationResult>boolean</CheckAuthenticationResult>
    </CheckAuthenticationResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

For consuming the above service I implemented the following code:

```
public static Boolean isAuthenticated(String UserName, String Password)
{
    String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    String METHOD_NAME = "CheckAuthentication";
    String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CheckAuthentication";
    String URL = "http://primehangout.com/primehangoutweb.asmx";

    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("UserId");
    pi.setValue(UserName);
    pi.setType(String.class);
    Request.addProperty(pi);

    PropertyInfo pi2 = new PropertyInfo();
    pi2.setName("Password");
    pi2.setValue(Password);
    pi2.setType(String.class);
    Request.addProperty(pi2);


    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
    try
    {
    AndroidHttpTransport transp = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
    transp.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

    return Boolean.parseBoolean(result.toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }


    return false;
}
```

It's working fine..
But now I'm going to consume a service.
The required service's request format is as follow:

```
POST /primehangoutweb.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: primehangout.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/GetComment"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <AuthSoapHd xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <strUserName>string</strUserName>
      <strPassword>string</strPassword>
    </AuthSoapHd>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetComment xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <UId>string</UId>
      <refID>int</refID>
    </GetComment>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And response of desired service is following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
        <GetCommentResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
          <GetCommentResult>
            <xsd:schema>schema</xsd:schema>xml</GetCommentResult>
        </GetCommentResponse>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

I've consumed the same services in my previous iPhone application using XMLReader classes but as I'm a newbie in android, I need your help guys.

:)

Thanks to all for reading my post!

Comment: you can see my complete answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51255957/soap-request-creation-using-ksoap2-for-multilevel-tags/51340332#51340332) for the same

Answer (score 1):

For Integrating KSoap 2 You have to add dependency to your build.gradle file.

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.2'
 }
```

Modify `AndroidManifest.xml`
In order to make soap calls on a web service exposed on the internet, additional permissions need to be added.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Then dive into code

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String SOAP_ACTION = "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/FahrenheitToCelsius";
                String METHOD_NAME = "FahrenheitToCelsius";
                String NAMESPACE = "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/";
                String URL = "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx";

                //Initialize soap request
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                //Use this to add parameters
                request.addProperty("Fahrenheit", "10");

                //Declare the version of the SOAP request
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                try {
                    //Needed to make the internet call
                    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                    List<HeaderProperty> headerList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
                    headerList.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encode((username + ":" + password).getBytes())));

                    transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headerList);
                    //Get the Response from the envelope body.
                    SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("TESTS", "KSOAP2", e);
                }
            }
        };

        thread.start();
```

Comment: I have the same problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325382/xmlpullparserexception-expected-with-ksoap2 . Can you help me?