# how to Call ksoap web service from android

Tags: android, sql-server

I would like to use `ksoap` lib in android studio . 
but I haven't enough acknowledged about it. 
(I always use `Volley` lib to send/receive from a php api and it works fine. )

URL address :
http://sms141.ir/sms141_webservice.asmx

my function :

```
public object[] CheckUsers(string number , string user  , string pass)
```

---

`SOAP_ACTION` and `NAMESPACE` variables are correct ?

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://sms141.ir/CheckUsers";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "CheckUsers";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://sms141.ir";
private static final String URL = "http://sms141.ir/sms141_webservice.asmx";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sms_login);

    myAsyncTask myRequest = new myAsyncTask();
    myRequest.execute();

}


private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
       // tv.setText(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("number", "value");
        request.addProperty("user", "value");
        request.addProperty("pass", "value");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        httpTransport.debug = true;
        try {
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        }catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } //send request
        SoapObject result = null;
        try {
            result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
        } catch (SoapFault e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d("App",""+result.getProperty(1).toString());
        String response = result.getProperty(1).toString();


        Log.e("result","0"+response);


        return null;
    }
}
```

I get these errors :

```
> 06-17 18:32:02.751  11495-11515/com.almas.mehr.sms E/AndroidRuntime﹕
> FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>             at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
>             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
>             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
>             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
>             at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
>      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>             at com.almas.mehr.sms.Login$myAsyncTask.doInBackground(Login.java:211)
>             at com.almas.mehr.sms.Login$myAsyncTask.doInBackground(Login.java:166)
>             at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
>             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
>             at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 1):

As from what I have understood your question you just need to know how to use KSOAP2 library with android to communicate with server.

Here is a link by which you will get the implementation

http://karanbalkar.com/2014/03/tutorial-78-using-ksoap2-in-android/

[How to use KSoap 2 in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155027/how-to-use-ksoap-2-in-android)